# Look for string in a range of lines and pick all the string after a particular and append it another file

Tags: python, perl

I have `file 1` contents as

```
wire x;
wire y;
input a;
input b;
input c;
reg m;
reg n;
```

I have to put signals `a`, `b`, `c` only in another file `file 2` in the following manner

```
assign inst.a=;
assign inst.b=;
assign inst.c=;
```

Can anyone please help me out on this issue using Perl or Python?

Comment: SO is not a code writing service.

Comment: Sounds like a job offer. here's my price: 15$/h, I accept bank transfer and bitcoins :)

Answer (score 1):

This one-line Perl program

```
perl -lne 'print "assign inst.$1=;" if /^input\h+(\w+);/' 'file 1'
```